# What are the differences between the cut and uncut versions of "Naruto" anime (not "Shippuden")?

Tags: naruto

I have watched the cut and uncut versions and haven't really noticed any differences.

What are the big (or even small) differences between each?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uncut episodes are typically longer, while CN cuts scenes out so they can show commercials. Uncut episodes also have more blood, alcohol, and sexual things in it. For example, the uncut episodes will show Naruto and Sasuke kissing in the beginning of the series, and they take that out on the CN version.

There's a comparison between a US TV version and Japanese TV version. Uncut episodes are most likely same as the Japanese version where it doesn't get censored out. Though, there might be a very slight improvement on the uncut version, probably like the lines touch-up or something, it's very hard to spot with naked eyes.

[US Version]-------------------------------------------------[Japanese/Uncut Version]--------------------------------

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: wow never noticed that! thanks, also i originally watched naruto from a bunch of different sites that might or might not have been the uncut version, so half the episodes i saw were cut and the other half were uncut so it was kind of a mess, I'm currently watching it from one site at the moment, thanks!

Comment: Btw is there an uncut version of naruto shippuden?

Comment: @blakeharrisonakerz Yes it is. The latest one is at DVD Set 29 which will release in Jan 17, 2017. [Details here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Naruto:_Shippuden_episodes#Box_sets), and you can check the price [here](https://www.amazon.com/Naruto-Shippuden-Uncut-DVD-Set/dp/B01MEH96W3/ref=pd_sbs_74_t_1?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=2931Z5S1MSEQVXT8848F).

Comment: wow thanks! can't wait to see what i was missing out on when i watched the normal version, i appreciate it :D

Comment: This is like in One Piece where Sanji's cigarette is replaced by a lollipop or Luffy defeats Crocodile using his sweat instead of his blood.

Answer (score 0):

One of the examples is, in episode 18, the scene where Haku died is censored. They didn't show how Kakashi's lightning stricken him to death. The blood is also removed.

Answer (score -2):

In the German version, it's also like "this one beat the other one", while in the uncut version it's like "this one killed the other one".

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. We appreciate your contribution, but as of current, looks like it lacks detail. It'd be better if you could provide more info by [edit]ing your answer, like in which episode this occurs, or even add more examples (further reading: [answer]). Finally, consider taking a [tour] to understand how this site works in general. Thanks.